# How do I clear the previous frames of a canvas animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, html-canvas

I am trying to rotate an object, but all the previous frames still show up on the canvas. [Here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/xkLw054e/).

This didn't work:

```
this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.canvasWidth, this.canvascanvas.Height);
```

How I can make only the current frame visible?

Comment: this.canvascanvas.Height => this.canvas.canvasHeight. Or this.canvas.width and this.canvas.height.

Comment: @AlexandreDesbiens That's an answer. Post it! :)

Comment: @Anko This just felt like an anodyne fix not worthy of an answer. I did post it though, in case it does fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have a typo in the line you posted:

```
this.canvascanvas.Height
```

should be:

```
this.canvas.canvasHeight
```

Alternatively, you can use `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` as shown in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032179/how-do-i-get-the-width-and-height-of-a-html5-canvas).

**Debugging tip**

When this type of code snippets don't work, try just outputting their values to the console with `console.log(...)`. In your case, outputting the value of `this.canvascanvas.Height` would have wield `undefined`, which would have been a clear indication that something is wrong with the variable (in this case, that it doesn't exist).